# code for value.counts() in columns pretaining to a specific value in one column

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, data-science

I'm new to data science and trying to do some data wrangling with python 2.7 in iPython notebook. A tutorial I was following for my first project asked me to replace all NaN intputs with 0 or 1. But I'd like to consider another approach where I can 1st look at the count for the rows with non-numerical values corresponding to all rows having credit_history as NaN...

Ideal Output when Credit_History is NaN:

```
Self_Employed
Yes  532
No   32

Married
No   398
Yes  213
```

And for the numerical values, I'd like to get the mean for all columns when credit_history is NaN

Ideal output for non-numberical values when Credit_History is NaN:

```
Mean Applicant Income: 54003.1232
LoanAmount: 35435.12
Loan_Amount_Term: 360
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For value counts, you can use [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df.loc[pd.isnull(df['Credit_History']), 'Self_Employed'].value_counts()
df.loc[pd.isnull(df['Credit_History']), 'Married'].value_counts()
```

For calculating mean, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

```
cols = ['Applicant_Income', 'LoanAmount', 'Loan_Amount_Term']

df.loc[pd.isnull(df['Credit_History']), cols].mean()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked!

If credit history is 0 90% of the time when Education is Not Graduate, how do we use fillna() to impute 0 for all education as 0?

Also if credit_history is 1 when Education is Graduate and ApplicantIncome is > 3500, how do we use fillna() to impute the credit_history using the two conditions?

Comment: @uharsha33, i advise you ask a separate question again.